# best practices for keep states of page in react-router application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I Have react app which contains many pages. For each page i added store. I using params from url for example photoId then passing to actioncreator which call service and then dispatching data to store. In page component i have store listener. Store imiting change and listener calling render for new state.
Store and action creator relates to this page only. How to create pages more simple? 
Thank you!

Comment: in [this example](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) i see that there are no any stores and action creators. just calling services on component is this good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flux model (using actions, dispatcher, and stores) works well for larger apps where a data fetch may affect many components and pages. If you think your app will grow then it may be worth the extra verbosity. If you're keeping your app small then composing plain React components is a great way to keep things simple and there is nothing wrong with doing it as long as you separate the data operations from the display, the way your linked example showed. Have fun!